# FormButtons misalignment?

Tags: excel, vba, alignment, excel-2007, rows

I am currently having an issue with form button misalignment with the rows. I am running the following code and getting different results each time. As per snap shot below, it appears that unless I zoom to 100% view, the following misalignment occurs. Does anyone have a solution?

Main Procedure:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    '   Sub ColumnA_Buttons()
        Dim buttons As Button
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim LineQty As Variant

            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            ActiveSheet.buttons.Delete

        LineQty = 20

        For i = 1 To LineQty
            Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1))
            Set buttons = ActiveSheet.buttons.Add(rng.Left, rng.Top, rng.Width, rng.Height)

                With buttons
                    .OnAction = "Buttons"
                    .Caption = "Line " & i
                    .Name = "Line " & i
                    End With
            Next i

            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       End Sub
```

Button Module:

```
Sub buttons()
    Dim Btn As Variant

     Btn = Application.Caller

     'MyUserForm1.Show 'Launch custom userform
     MsgBox Btn & "  was Clicked"

End Sub
```

[image: Excel Misalignment]

Comment: Your code aligns exactly as expected for me: http://i.imgur.com/F1ypKi8.png (running Excel 2013 - works in all magnifications but 70% is depicted). Could be a 2007 thing? Can someone else with 2007 verify?

Comment: In Excel 2010 they also align perfectly at various zoom levels.

Comment: Hey thanks Laur for confirming the issue.

I have also tested with Active-X controls, demonstrating that OLEObjects suffer from the same misalignment issue. My research has also shown that this is a concurrent issue in Excel versions' at least involving, and up to Ver07. Any solutions welcomed, or comments based on experience ?

Thanks again in advance ;)